# How can i get the Payload in a daemon node?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm a total beginner in Using Node-Red and nodeJS. Im trying to write nodejs code in an "daemon node" for handling my payload before sending it by MQTT to my nodejs Server. My Problem is: I can't get my payload from stdin.

I tried everything i found online about reading from stdin, but I didn't find a solution.

```
"use strict"

let mqtt = require("mqtt");
let client  = mqtt.connect("mqtt://192.168.178.36");

let obj = process.stdin;
console.log(obj);

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("Sending...")
    client.publish("test/reader01", "Reader01: " + (new Date()).toString() + "\n" + obj);
    client.end();
});
```

The program you can see here sends the aktual Date to the server an prints out a string including a net.socket object on the console, but i can't get the payload from my stream.

Comment: you want the payload to be printed on your terminal ?

Comment: Why do you want to run an external NodeJS program with the daemon node when everything in that can be done in a native Node-RED flow?